# Value of char c = 255 converted to unsigned int in c++

Tags: c++, char, unsigned-integer

I have the following code:

```
char c= 128;
printf("The value of c is %u.", c);
```

where the output is a large number (rubish!) and not 128.

I expected with an unsigned integer (%u), and with 8 bits (the size of char), I could represent the values 0 to 255. But it only represents up to 127.

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: 8bits represent 0 to 255 only for `unsigned char`, `char` on your platform is signed

Comment: Use `unsigned char` instead of `char`.

Comment: @abdy.  Curious, Why was the output value  not posted instead of only "output is a large number (rubish!)"?  As you are asking, might the assessment that it is rubbish be in error?